# How to do something like jQuery's $("#formID").submit() event using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form with some fields. When user fills all fields and submits the form, I force user to register or login(in modal window) before form submission.

That is, when user try to submit the form, I first open a modal window with login form(user can toggle register/login form). After user complete the login/register form and submit it, I send all data using ajax and after I get a success status, I submit the previous form using jQuery's $("formID").submit() event.

Now as I am migrating from jQuery to angularJS I have tried to find a solution to do that using angularJS, I have completed the user registration/login part using angularJS's **$http service**, but have failed to submit the previous form data.

Is there any angularJS solution to that kind thing? Is it possible to submit a form with its ID or something like this?

Comment: Of course not. The form is meant to be data-bound directly to a $scope property. If the posted answer is not working for you, you have done something majorly wrong in your code dealing with the modal. I use modals in my apps and have no problems using the data-binding and directives available.

Comment: @m59 -- please read again my problem... I think you haven't understand my problem.

Comment: I posted an answer with a full demonstration (using a div to simulate your modal). All you need to do is see the comments on the submit function and use either the $http success callback or MUCH BETTER use promises with the `.then()` function.

Comment: You have not accepted an answer. Is your question not answered?

Comment: LOL. Then could you please explain why? My answer demonstrates exactly what you are trying to do, unless your question is unclear. I even wrote the code for you, which is pretty generous.

Comment: @m59-- you are trying to help me it is really great! I appreciate it.... Ok, i'm trying to make it more clear

Comment: Ok, your edit still sounds just like it did before, which is what my answer is doing. You fill out the form, click submit, open a modal to login, user logs in, form is submitted. If you don't understand my answer, tell me what specifically you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have done everything you requested. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/aVehufU/2/edit)

```
  <div ng-show="successMessage">
    <p>{{successMessage}}</p>
    <h6>Form data sent:</h6>
    <p ng-repeat="(k,v) in form track by k">{{k}}: {{v}}</p>
  </div>
  <form ng-submit="mySubmit()" ng-hide="modalOpen||successMessage">
    <input ng-model="form.name" placeholder="Name">
    <input ng-model="form.phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <div ng-show="modalOpen">
    <h6>This would be your modal.</h6>
    <p>Login to submit form!<p>
    <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.form = {
    name: '',
    phone: ''
  };
  $scope.modalOpen = false;
  $scope.mySubmit = function() {
    $scope.modalOpen = true; 
  };
  $scope.login = function() {
     $scope.loggedIn = true; //should come from a service and use promise, send form after promise resolves using .then()
    //dataService.sendForm() or however you want to submit the form. the same principle applies about using a promise and .then() function to set the successMessage and close modal.
    $scope.successMessage = 'Form is submitted!';
    $scope.modalOpen = false;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

check this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSubmit

```
<form ng-submit="{expression}">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: this will not work as I am opening modal window on form submission and after register/login is complete, I am actually submitting previous form data.